# Docker node cannot find file on mounted volume

Tags: node.js, linux, docker

I'm trying to run a docker container that has a volume mounted on it that contains ssl keys/files.
I keep getting a file not found error when I've triple-looked at all the directories and the error and can't seem to wonder what is going on.

To start off,
here's the portion of my code that I'm trying to run that's throwing errors:
[image: code_source_pick]

Here's the docker run command that I'm using:
[image: docker_run_command]

Here's the error (with the path that it tried to find the file at):
[image: error_image]

I've decided to dig into the container and try to see if the files are really there, which they are:
[image: proofss]

Again, the paths seem to line up when seeing the error path (the path shown when the error was thrown), and the pwd path (digging into the docker container). Not sure why it cannot find the file.

Comment: can you please post the output of `ls -ltra` inside the certs folder?

Comment: @HernanGarcia Hey! Sorry, I had just found the fix. If what you were looking for were to check and see if the files were symlinks/symbolic links, well they are. I went and retrieved the original files and now the program actually sees the files.

Comment: Good to hear that you managed it to solve it ;-) have a good coding!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The files were actually symlinks/symbolic links, so I went to go retrieve the original files that they were linked up to and used those. The program now sees the files clearly.